# IBM Connections mobile application - any registered URL handlers?

Tags: ios, url, mobile, ibm-connections

On a mobile unit (iOS in this case) - I need to be able to open the connections mobile application to a particular profile, something like this: https://connectionsServer.com/profiles/html/profileView.do?userid=theProfileUID&lang=en_us

Triggering this URL would open the Connections application (if installed) and displaying the corresponding profile.

I doubt that IBM thought of it, but I you never know...

Thanks!

/J

Comment: Are you at IBM Connect? Chris Reckling is going to present on this on Wednesday

Comment: Unfortunately now, but some of my colleagues are. We'll check this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL scheme for the IBM Connections app is of the form `ibmscp://com.ibm.connections/`.
Opening the app to a profile like your example would be done by opening the URL `ibmscp://com.ibm.connections/profiles?userid=theProfileUID`.

More information can be found on [this IBM page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21601146).